# Neo4j - Separating result rows in to logical components

Tags: neo4j

Because Neo4j returns a row for every return object, it has the possibility to return rows with duplicate properties.

How do I turn this set of rows in to a suitable data structure? Specifically I want to comb through each row and set duplicate values as a property, and for the ones I expect to be different, add them to an array so I end up with something more readable. For example, turning something like this:

```
[
 [“event” = “My Event”, “creator” = “Adam”, “occurrence” = “1/2/3”],
 [“event” = “My Event”, “creator” = “Adam”, “occurrence” = “2/3/4”],
 [“event” = “My Event”, “creator” = “Adam”, “occurrence” = “3/4/5”],
 [“event” = “Event 2”, “creator” = “Someone”, “occurrence” = “4/2/3”],
 [“event” = “Event 2”, “creator” = “ Someone”, “occurrence” = “4/3/4”],
 [“event” = “Event 2”, “creator” = “ Someone”, “occurrence” = “6/4/5”],
]
```

into something more readable and non cluttered as this:

```
[
 [“event” = “My Event”, “creator” = “Adam”, “occurrence” = [“1/2/3”, “2/3/4 ”, “3/4/5”]],
 [“event” = “Event 2”, “creator” = “ Someone”, “occurrence” = [“4/2/3”, “4/3/4”, “6/4/5”]]
]
```

UPDATE:

This is my query,

```
MATCH (creator:CreatingUser)-[:creator]-(event:Event), (occurrence:EventSpaceTimeOccurrence)-[:occurrence]-(event)
WHERE creator.id = '1234'
RETURN event, creator, occurrence
```

Where I expect one event, one eventType, one creator and many occurrences. The above query gives me results as above which I want to collapse in to the non cluttered version above.

Comment: I should mention I’m using PHP, so if there are any specific functions you recommend that might be useful

Comment: to clarify your question, create a dataset using http://console.neo4j.org and share it here.

Comment: Have you looked at aggregating your results using `collect`? See http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect. Without more detail of what query you are running and your graph it is hard to suggest a query to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, please see update for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your edit I would suggest the following

```
MATCH (creator:CreatingUser)-[:creator]-(event:Event), (occurrence:EventSpaceTimeOccurrence)-[:occurrence]-(event)
RETURN event, creator, collect(occurrence) as eventoccurrences
```

This will result in one row per unique combination of event and creator, plus a collection of occurrences for this combination. If you are only interested in specific properties then you can collect these. For example if you had an `eventdate` property you could use

```
RETURN event, creator, collect(occurrence.eventdate) as eventdates
```

Now you will get a collection of your `eventdate` property. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the PHP language driver so cannot suggest a function. I know in other languages there are equivalents to collect. HTH!

Comment: My problem really comes from the fact that I can have many different rows too. So there could return many events, many creators and many occurrences. The event and creator can double up (as above) but all occurrences will be different.

Comment: Oh. Your example query would only return one result and that is what I based the answer on. Unless you have multiple events with the same value for `event.id`? If you omit the `WHERE` clause then you would get a row for each combination of event, creator and then collection of event dates. Would this do it?

Comment: Yeah, apologies, I realised that this can be different. Please see my updated examples of return values and preferred output

Comment: My updated query is intended to base the results around the `creator` entity

Comment: So you want one row per `creator`?

Comment: That’s right, where we collect the occurrences as an array

Comment: So in effect your output would be `[“creator” = “Adam”, “event” = [“My Event 1”, "My Event 2"], “occurrence” = [“1/2/3”, “2/3/4 ”, “3/4/5”]]`??

Comment: No, it would be as above in the expected output

Comment: Specifically this: `[
 [“event” = “My Event”, “creator” = “Adam”, “occurrence” = [“1/2/3”, “2/3/4 ”, “3/4/5”]],
 [“event” = “Event 2”, “creator” = “ Someone”, “occurrence” = [“4/2/3”, “4/3/4”, “6/4/5”]]
]`

Comment: OK - have edited. Still think if you remove the `WHERE` clause it will achieve your objective...

Comment: With a bit [lot] of code changes, I’ve managed to do it thanks to your query suggestion, thanks a lot!